# Internet explorer 9 not displaying PNG image

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

I have a problem with my page [here](http://www.tinywolf.uk)where the logo (which is meant to be to the left of the title) is not showing. It works in firefox and chrome.

this is the markup:

```
<div class="header-container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="logo"> <img src="/images/Tiny-Wolf-Logo-ICN.png" alt="Tiny Logo" width="120px" height="120px">
            </div>
            <div class="title">Tiny Wolf
            </div> 
            <div class="tagline">Visual Storytellers
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

I have tested to see if this is a CMYK issue but is not. I have also declared width and height but the image is still not appearing.

Comment: Looking at it in console it seems that it's using this line from your CSS: /*@media only screen and (min-width:600px)*/
.logo {
    display: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you mentioned css/main.css line-no. 242

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {           

    .logo { display: none;}
}
```

So only logo not display in IE browsers. 
and you ask why if display other browser?.

that answer is you write css/main.css line-no. 73

```
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Just put the !important for this place ex:

```
.logo {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

it display well.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add a !important on line 74 of your `main.css.` Like this:

```
display: inline-block !important;
```

So, in any IE you will see the PNG.

Comment: The image will display but this breaks the layout of the page. When I add this the image does not display inline (it appears above the logo) and the media queries for the logo do not work.(although these did not work before either - see chrome or firefox at widescreen vs tablet/phone to see how this should look)

Comment: Maybe because you're using 2 different div's. One with `logo` class to display the logo and one with the `title` class to display the title.
Try putting them in a div only. This makes the page does not break.